# Refrigerator Water Shut Off Valve

Tags: water, plumbing-fixture

We are getting a new refrigerator and just found out that the shut off valve has to be on the same floor/level as the appliance. Our current fridge water shut off valve is in the basement-my question is, is this a fairly simple job to add a shut off valve to the existing water line, behind the refrigerator??

Comment: Who told you that the refrigerator required a shutoff on the same floor? I have found quite a few in the basement. I am not a plumber but if the shutoff is already accessible in your home I would tell them to stuff it.

Answer (score 1):

It should be a simple task to add a shutoff valve to the existing line. You probably have 1/4" copper tubing or polyethylene tubing. There are shutoff valves available for either type and they don't require soldering. Cut your existing line where you'd like the valve and take the piece to your home store or a plumbing supply store to get the proper valve. Remember to shut off the line in the basement before doing any disassembly.